# Auto-indent spaces with C in vim?

Tags: c, vim, coding-style, vi

I've been somewhat spoiled using Eclipse and java.  I started using vim to do C coding in a linux environment, is there a way to have vim automatically do the proper spacing for blocks?

So after typing a { the next line will have 2 spaces indented in, and a return on that line will keep it at the same indentation, and a } will shift back 2 spaces?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

These two commands should do it:

```
:set autoindent
:set cindent
```

For bonus points put them in a file named .vimrc located in your home directory on linux

Comment: I would also recommend putting those into ~.vim/ftplugin/c.vim so that you're not using cindent all the time, but only for C/C++ files.

Comment: @graywh: What about for pl, php, cpp, as, java, and all the other files I want to have the same indenting? Do I need to create a separate settings file for each one?

Comment: I rely Vim's bundled indent scripts (:filetype indent on) which is *much* better than just using 'cindent' always.

Comment: why filetype indentation is better than using cindent is well explained here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code#Methods_for_automatic_indentation

Comment: For autoindent, you might want to use the shorthand :set ai

Answer (score 61):

I [wrote all about tabs in vim](http://tedlogan.com/techblog3.html), which gives a few interesting things you didn't ask about. To automatically indent braces, use:

```
:set cindent
```

To indent two spaces (instead of one tab of eight spaces, the vim default):

```
:set shiftwidth=2
```

To keep vim from converting eight spaces into tabs:

```
:set expandtab
```

If you ever want to change the indentation of a block of text, use < and >. I usually use this in conjunction with block-select mode (v, select a block of text, < or >).

(I'd try to talk you out of using two-space indentation, since I (and most other people) find it hard to read, but that's another discussion.)

Comment: Very nice blog.  I'm still fairly new to vim, nice to know there's good resources out there though.

Comment: You also missed changing softtabstop in addition to shiftwidth.

Answer (score 8):

A lot of vim's features (like `autoindent` and `cindent`) are turned off by default.  To really see what vim can do for you, you need a decent `~/.vimrc`.

A good starter one is in `$VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim`.  If you want to try it out, use

```
:source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
```

when in vim.

I'd actually suggest just copying the contents to your `~/.vimrc` as it's well commented, and a good place to start learning how to use vim.  You can do this by

```
:e $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
:w! ~/.vimrc
```

This will overwrite your current `~/.vimrc`, but if all you have in there is the indent settings Davr suggested, I wouldn't sweat it, as the example vimrc will take care of that for you as well.  For a complete walkthrough of the example, and what it does for you, see `:help vimrc-intro`.

Answer (score 5):

### Simply run:

```
user@host:~ $ echo set autoindent >> .vimrc
```

Comment: I was not the one who down-voted, but it was probably because simply "set autoindent" does not on its own auto-indent upon typing "{" and "}", and nor does it automatically set the spacing to 2 spaces. This is what they asked for.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best answer is actually explained on the vim wikia:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code

Note that it advises against using "set autoindent."  The best feature of all I find in this explanation is being able to set per-file settings, which is especially useful if you program in python and C++, for example, as you'd want 4 spaces for tabs in the former and 2 for spaces in the latter.

Answer (score 0):

and always remember this venerable explanation of Spaces + Tabs:

http://www.jwz.org/doc/tabs-vs-spaces.html

Comment: What is with that guy's argument? I don't follow how not using the TAB character, and filling with hard-coded spaces instead, solves everyone's problems. That would make it impossible, for example, to be able to open a file and have the width of its indents appear according to your own preferences.

Comment: This guy's solution is much better :)
http://blogs.msdn.com/cyrusn/archive/2004/09/14/229474.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Try:

set sw=2

set ts=2

set smartindent

Comment: According to the help, cindent is better than smartindent, but only works for C-like code.

Comment: smartindent is deprecated (was only for C-like code, too).  Filetype indent scripts are much better.

Comment: @graywh besides the wiki which authoritative source states the deprecated status of smartindent?